# Can we define the derivative of a function in arbitrary metric space in the following way?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let us first define some terms.

> **Definition of Pre-pseudometric**
>
> Let $X\ne\emptyset$ and a function $\varphi:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ will be called a *pre-pseudometric* on $X$ if,
>
> 1. $x=y\implies \varphi(x,y)=0$
> 2. $\varphi(x,y)=-\varphi(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in X$
> 3. $\varphi(x,y)=\varphi(x,z)+\varphi(z,y)$ for all $x,y,z\in X$
>
> **Definition of Pre-pseudometric Space**
>
> Let $X\ne\emptyset$ and $\varphi$ is a pre-pseudometric on $X$. Then $\langle X,\varphi\rangle$ will be called the *pre-pseudometric space $X$ with pre-pseudometric $\varphi$*.

It may be of interest to note at this point that if $\varphi$ is a pre-pseudometric on a non-empty set $X$ then a pseudometric $d_\varphi$ can be obtained from $\varphi$ by defining $d_\varphi(x,y)=|\varphi(x,y)|$.

Conversely, if $d_\varphi$ be a pseudometric on $X$ then function $\varphi(x,y)=d_\varphi(a,x)-d_\varphi(a,y)$ is a pre-pseudometric on $X$ where $a\in X$ is a fixed element.

> **Definition of Derivative of a Function in a Pre-pseudometric Space**
>
> Let $f:\langle X,\varphi_X\rangle \to \langle Y,\varphi_Y\rangle$. We will say that $f$ is differentiable at $a\in X$ if for all sequence $(\sigma_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $\sigma_n:=\dfrac{\varphi_Y(f(x_n),f(a))}{\varphi_X(x_n,a)}$ with $x_n\in X\setminus \{a\}$ and $\varphi_X(x_n,a)\ne 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$ we have, $$\left|\dfrac{\varphi_Y(f(x_n),f(a))}{\varphi_X(x_n,a)}-L\right|<\varepsilon$$ for some $L\in \mathbb{R}$ and for all sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

If this happens then we will say that $f$ is differentiable in the system $\bigl(\langle X,\varphi_X\rangle, \langle Y,\varphi_Y\rangle\bigr)$ and the derivative of the function at $x=a$ exists. We will then denote this derivative by $f'(a)$ and say that $f'(a)=L$.

> **Definition of Relative Derivative of a Function in a Pseudometric Space**
>
> We will say that a function $f$ is relatively differentiable in a pseudometric space $(X,d_\varphi)$ if *with respect to a pre-pseudometric $\varphi$ that can be obtained from $d_\varphi$* it is differentiable in the pre-pseudometric space $\langle X,\varphi\rangle$.
>
> **Definition of Absolute Derivative of a Function in a Pseudometric Space**
>
> We will say that a function $f$ is absolutely differentiable in a pseudometric space $(X,d_\varphi)$ if *with respect to every pre-pseudometric $\varphi$ that can be obtained from $d_\varphi$* it is differentiable in the pre-pseudometric space $\langle X,\varphi\rangle$.

Since a metric space is always a pseudometric space, I think that we have defined differentiation in an arbitrary metric space.

---

### **Question**

> Can we define the notion of "differentiation" or the "derivative of a function" as I have defined above?

Comment: Of possible interest: [*Metric derived numbers and continuous metric differentiability via homeomorphisms*](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/~malevao/papers/metrdernum.pdf) by Jakub Duda and Olga Maleva (2006); [*On relations among metric derived numbers*](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/702532/ActaCarolinae_050-2009-2_5.pdf) by Martin Koc (2009); [*Differential equations in metric spaces*](http://www.emis.de/journals/MB/127.2/mb127_2_22.pdf)
by Jacek Tabor (2002)

Comment: Also of possible interest: [**Generalized Ordinary Differential Equations in Metric Spaces**](https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~rokyta/vyuka/Mgr-statnice/diplomky/1314-09_Skovajsa_DP.pdf) by Bøetislav Skovajsa (2014 Ph.D. Dissertation)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "can be obtained from?"

Comment: @M10687: Means that for each pre-pseudometric $\varphi$ we can always construct a pseudometric $d_\varphi$.

Comment: Note that if you choose a point $x_0\in X$, a pre-pseudometric $\varphi$ on $X$ is equivalent to just any map $p:X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $p(x_0)=0$: given $\varphi$ you can define $p(x)=\varphi(x,x_0)$, and given $p$, you can define $\varphi(x,y)=p(x)-p(y)$.

Comment: Re: Absolute  derivaive : We can obtain a pseudo-metric from a pre-pseudo-metric. But how do  we obtain a pre-pseudo-metric from a pseudo-metric?

Comment: @user254665: Why do we need to obtain a pre-pseudo-metric from a pseudo-metric? The point here is to define the notion of derivative in more general spaces than the metric spaces.

Comment: You stated "... with respect to every pre-pseudo-metric  $\psi$  that can be obtained from $d_{\psi}$....". That's why.

Comment: @user254665: For that I think that if $d_φ$ be a given pseudometric then you can define $φ(x,y)=d_φ(x,a)−d_φ(y,a)$ (where $a\in X$ and $a$ is fixed) and then $φ$ will be a pre-pseudometric.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could comment ...

You wrote
''Since a metric space is always a pseudometric space, I think that we have defined differentiation in an arbitrary metric space.''

However, you didn't mention how you define a metric using a given pseudometric.  I submit that the usual distance function on the real line is a metric that is not a pseudometric, in the sense that you defined.  In fact, it is not even a prepseudometric, because if $x=1$,$y=2$, and $z=3$, then

d(x,y)=1,

while

$d(x,z)+d(z,y)=2+1=3\neq d(x,y)$.

Consequently, your approach does not define any kind of derivative in arbitrary metric spaces.