# Topological spaces which are not pseudometrizable.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Then we know some conditions under which $(X,\tau)$ is metrizable (see for example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%E2%80%93Smirnov_metrization_theorem) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_metrization_theorem)). It is also clear from these theorems that not every topological space is metrizable.

However, I am wondering whether the same is true for pseudometric spaces also. To be more specific,

> Does there exist topological spaces which are not pseudometrazible?

Where we agree to call a topological space $(X,\tau)$ to be pseudometrizable iff  there exists a pseudometric $d$ on $X$ such that the topology induced by the psuedometric is $\tau$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pseudometric space is symmetric (also called [$R_0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space)): if $x \in \overline{\{y\}}$ then $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$ (basically because $d(x,y)=0$ implies $d(y,x)=0$ too, also in pseudometric spaces).

Sierpinski space ($X=\{0,1\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset,\{0\},X\}$) is not symmetric so not pseudometrisable. (Because $1 \in \overline{\{0\}}$ but not the other way around). This is in a way the simplest example, certainly the smallest one.

If $X$ is $T_1$ then $X$ is metrisable iff $X$ is pseudometrisable. (the $T_1$ ensures that $X$ is also $R_0$ and so the non-existence of any points $x,y$ with $x \neq y$ but $d(x,y)=0$. So the pseudometric for $X$ on the right is then a metric.)

So spaces like the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{N}$ is not pseudometrisable, as it's not metrisable (not Hausdorff to start with...)
Also, the Sorgenfrey line, the Michael line, double arrow space etc etc.

Comment: Does there exists any generalization of the notion of metric, say for the time being, a generalized metric such that every topological space is generalized metrizable?

Comment: @user170039 there probably is (I've seen such things at conferences and immediately forgot), but what would be the point?

Comment: Actually I am trying to define the notion of [differentiable functions for arbitrary topological space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/332653/a-definition-of-differentiable-functions-for-arbitrary-topological-spaces). I can already do so for metric spaces (a sketch of idea is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640360/can-we-define-the-derivative-of-a-function-in-arbitrary-metric-space-in-the-foll)) and hope to extend these ideal to general topological spaces.

Comment: In case you happen to find reference for any such thing, please let me know. It will help me immensely.

Answer (score 4):

The [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) is not pseudometrizable. The [Kolmogorov quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_space#The_Kolmogorov_quotient) of a pseudometric space [is metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space#Metric_identification). However the Sierpinski space is already $T_0$, but it's not Hausdorff, and thus not metric.

The Sierpinski space is the topological space on two points with the topology
$$\{\varnothing, \{0\}, \{0,1\}\}.$$